# Error when trying to connect to the google auth api

Tags: python, json, google-api, credentials

I'm trying to create a vocal assistant using the google API but I continue to get a bad request when trying to run my code when connecting to the google API.

I'm using python in VScode on a mac and in the past it had worked until it blocked my account when i mistakenly sent too many requests.

Can anyone help with this.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from http import server
from lib2to3.pygram import python_grammar_no_print_statement
import pickle
import os.path
import smtplib
import webbrowser
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
import os
import datetime
import time
from datetime import timedelta
import pyttsx3
import speech_recognition as sr
import pytz
import subprocess
import wikipedia
import pyjokes
import mysql.connector
import requests
import wolframalpha

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host = "localhost",
    user = "root",
    password = "6alvise2005",
    database = "noradb")

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly']
MONTHS = ["january", "february", "march", "april", "may", "june", "july", "august", "septmeber", "october", "november", "dicember"]
DAYS = ["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday"]
DAY_EXTENTIONS = ["st", "nd", "rd", "th"]

def speak(text):
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()

def get_audio(): # returns the text version of what the user says into the microphone
    r = sr.Recognizer() # creating a recognisable object from the speach ricognition module
    with sr.Microphone() as source: # use the microphone to listen 
        audio = r.listen(source)
        said = ""

        try:
            said = r.recognize_google(audio) # use the Google API to recognise what has been said
            print(said)
        except Exception as e: # to avoid any error if the micrphone doesn't hear anything
            print("Exception: " + str(e))

    return said.lower() # everything will be turned to lower case to avoid any kind of missunderstanding and eventual problems

def authenticate_google():
    creds = None
    if os.path.exists('token.json'): # the file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, 
                                     # and is created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first time
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    if not creds or not creds.valid: # if there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                '/Users/alvisebaracco/Desktop/computerIA/credentials.json', SCOPES) # location of the json file
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
            print("error1") 
        with open('/Users/alvisebaracco/Desktop/computerIA/token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json()) # saves the credentials for the next run in a kind of local cache

    service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=creds)

    return service # this makes theis code run at the start of the program and return the service that contains the google calendar for the user
 
def get_events(date, service):
        date = datetime.datetime.combine(date, datetime.datetime.min.time()) # retrieving the start date from the previously apploaded event
        end_date = datetime.datetime.combine(date, datetime.datetime.max.time()) # retrieving the end date from the previously apploaded event
        utc = pytz.UTC
        date = date.astimezone(utc) # retrieving the start time from the previously apploaded event
        end_date = end_date.astimezone(utc) # retrieving the end time from the previously apploaded event

        events_result = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', timeMin=date.isoformat(), timeMax=end_date.isoformat(),
                                              singleEvents=True,
                                              orderBy='startTime').execute()
        events = events_result.get('items', [])

        if not events:
            speak('No upcoming events found.')
        else: 
            speak(f"You have {len(events)} events on this day.")

        for event in events:
            start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
            print(start, event['summary'])
            start_time = str(start.split("T")[1].split("-")[0]) # splits the different pieces of information
            if int(start_time.split("-")[0]) < 12:
                start_time = start_time + "am"
            else:
                start_time = str(int(start_time.split("-")[0]) - 12) + start_time.split(":")[1]
                start_time = start_time + "pm"

            speak(event["summary"] + "at" + start_time)

def get_date(text):
    text = text.lower()
    today = datetime.date.today()

    if text.count("today") > 0 :
        return today # if we see the word 'today' the code will return the current date

    day = -1
    day_of_week = -1
    month = -1
    year = today.year

    for word in text.split(): # splits every word so that it is better to analyse
        if word in MONTHS: # see if there is any word in the MONTHS list
            month = MONTHS.index(word) + 1 # see which number each month corrisponds to 
        elif word in DAYS:
            day_of_week = DAYS.index(word) # same as MONTHS
        elif word.isdigit():
            day = int(word)
        else:
            for ext in DAY_EXTENTIONS:
                found = word.find(ext)
                if found > 0: # if we has something before that we see if it a digit and then try to turn it into a number 
                              # and if we can't we transfort it into a day
                    try:
                        day = int(word[:found])
                    except:
                        pass

    if month < today.month and month != -1: 
        year = year + 1 # if there is a month that is less compared to the month we are currently in have add 1 to the year

    if day < today.day and month == -1 and day != -1:
        month = month + 1 # same as before but for the day
    
    if month == -1 and day == -1 and day_of_week != -1:
        current_day_of_week = today.weekday() # which day of the week it is from 0 - 6 
        dif = day_of_week - current_day_of_week

        if dif < 0:
            dif += 7
            if text.count("next") >= 1:
                dif += 7
        
        return today + datetime.timedelta(dif)

    if month == -1 or day == -1:
        return None

    return datetime.date(month = month, day = day, year = year) # returns at the end the month, the date and the year of the requested event

def note(text):
    date = datetime.datetime.now()
    file_name = str(date).replace(":", "-") + "-note.txt"
    with open(file_name, "w") as f:
        f.write(text)

    Notes = "C:/usr/bin/open", "-W", "-n", "-a", "/Applications/Note.app" # occhio al 'C:'

WAKE = "hey nora"
SERVICE = authenticate_google()
print("Start")

def sendEmail (to, content):
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.ehlo()
    server. starttls()
    server.login('email@gmail.com', 'password')
    server.sendemail('email@gmail.com', to, content)
    server.close()

while True: 
    print("Listening")
    text = get_audio()

    if text.count(WAKE) < 0:
        speak("I am ready")
        text = get_audio()

        CALENDAR_STRS = ["what do i have", "do i have plans", "am i busy"]
        for phrase in CALENDAR_STRS:
            if phrase in text:
                date = get_date(text)
                if date:
                    get_events(date, SERVICE)
                else:
                    speak("I don't understand")

        NOTE_STRS = ["make a note", "write this down", "remember this"]
        for phrase in NOTE_STRS:
            if phrase in text:
                speak("What would you like me to write down?")
                note_text = get_audio()
                note(note_text)
                speak("I've made a note of that.")
                
        DATABASE = ["database", "table"]
        for phrase in DATABASE:
            if phrase in text:
                speak ("Ok, let's open MySQL")
                subprocess.call(["/usr/bin/open", "-W", "-n", "-a", "/Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app"])

        mycursor = mydb.cursor() # to access the database 
        
        DATABASE_ADD = ["add in database", "write in database", "take note of in the database"]
        for phrase in DATABASE_ADD:
            if phrase in text:
                subprocess.call(["/usr/bin/open", "-W", "-n", "-a", "/Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app"]) # opens MySQL
                speak ("Where would you like to add your information: appointments, notes or recipes?")
                add_type = get_audio() # retrieves what the clients says and searches if a precise word was said
                if add_type == 'appointments':
                    speak ("You want to write the title or the time of the appointment?")
                    appointment_type_add = get_audio()
                    if appointment_type_add == 'the title': # inserts in the decided table
                        speak ("What do you want to insert?")
                        add_title = get_audio()
                        mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO appointments (name) VALUES (%s)", (add_title)) # adds to the database what has just been answered to the question
                    else: # inserts the wanted data in the other row, different from 'title'
                        speak ("What do you want to insert?")
                        add_time = get_audio()
                        mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO appointments (dateandtime) VALUES (%s)", (add_time))
                elif add_type == 'notes':
                    speak ("What would you like me to write?")
                    add_note = get_audio()
                    mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO notes (note) VALUES (%s)", (add_note)) # adds to the database what has just been answered to the question
                elif add_type == 'recipe':
                    speak ("What will you cook next time?")
                    add_recipe = get_audio()
                    mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO recipe (name) VALUES (%s)", (add_recipe)) # adds to the database what has just been answered to the question
        
        mycursor.execute(sql)
        mydb.commit()
        cursor = mydb.cursor() # to conclude the modifications to the database

        DATABASE_DELETE = ["delete something in the database", "cancel something in the database"]
        for phrase in DATABASE_DELETE:
            if phrase in text:
                subprocess.call(["/usr/bin/open", "-W", "-n", "-a", "/Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app"])
                speak ("From where would you like to delete some data? appointments, notes or recipes")
                delete_type = get_audio()
                if delete_type == 'appointments':
                    speak ("Would you like to delete at first the tilte or the time of the latter?")
                    appointment_type_delete = get_audio()
                    if appointment_type_delete == 'title': # midifies the items in this table
                        speak ("Which title do you want to delete?")
                        delete_title = get_audio()
                        sql = "DELETE FROM appointments WHERE name = %s" # to delete what has been said from the client in the database
                        value_1 = (delete_title)
                        cursor.execute(sql, value_1) 
                        mydb.commit() # to conclude the modifications to the database
                    else:
                        speak ("Which time do you want to delete?")
                        delete_time = get_audio()
                        sql = "DELETE FROM appointments WHERE dateandtime = %s"
                        value_2 = (delete_time)
                        cursor.execute(sql, value_2)
                        mydb.commit() 
                elif delete_type == 'notes':
                    speak ("Which note do you want to delete?")
                    delete_note = get_audio()
                    sql = "DELETE FROM notes WHERE note = %s"
                    value_3 = (delete_note)
                    cursor.execute(sql, value_3)
                    mydb.commit()
                elif delete_type == 'recipes':
                    speak ("Which food you've already prepared and would like to delete?")
                    delete_recipe = get_audio()
                    sql = "DELETE FROM recipes WHERE name = %s"
                    value_4 = (delete_recipe)
                    cursor.execute(sql, value_4)
                    mydb.commit()

        if 'wikipedia' in text:
            speak('Searching Wikipedia...')
            query = text.replace("wikipedia", "")
            results = wikipedia.summary(query, sentences = 3)
            speak("According to Wikipedia")
            print(results)
            speak(results)

        elif 'email to maria' in text:
            try:
                speak ("What should I send him?")
                content = get_audio()
                to = "maria@eisp.it"
                sendEmail (to, content)
                speak ("The email has been successfully sent")
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                speak ("sorry I am not able to send this email")
        
        elif "calculate" or "what is" in text:
            question = get_audio()
            app_id = "Mention your API key"
            client = wolframalpha.Client(app_id)
            res = client.query(question)
            answer = next(res.resutls).text
            speak("The answer is " + answer)


        elif 'open whatsapp' in text:
            speak ("Ok, let's open WhatsApp")
            subprocess.call(["/usr/bin/open", "-W", "-n", "-a", "/Applications/WhatsApp.app"])

        elif 'open facebook' in text:
            speak ("Ok, let's open FaceBook")
            subprocess.call(["/usr/bin/open", "-W", "-n", "-a", "/Applications/Facebook.app"])

        elif 'open gmail' in text:
            speak ("Ok, let's open Gmail")
            subprocess.call(["/usr/bin/open", "-W", "-n", "-a", "/Applications/Gmail.app"])

        elif 'open youtube' in text:
            speak("Here you go to Youtube\n")
            webbrowser.open("https://www.youtube.com")

        elif 'open google' in text:
            speak("Here you go to Google\n")
            webbrowser.open("https://www.google.com/?client=safari")

        elif 'news' in text:
            speak ("Here are some news of the day on the BBC")
            webbrowser.open("https://www.bbc.com")

        elif 'play music' in text or "play song" in text:
            speak("Here you go with music")
            music_dir = "C:\\Users\\Alvise\\Music"
            songs = os.listdir(music_dir)
            print(songs)
            random = os.startfile(os.path.join(music_dir, songs[1]))

        elif 'the time' in text:
            strTime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("% H:% M:% S")
            speak(f"Sir, the time is {strTime}")

        elif 'how are you' in text:
            speak("I am fine, Thank you")
            speak("How are you, Sir")

        elif 'fine' in text or "good" in text:
            speak("It's good to know that your fine")

        elif 'exit' in text:
            speak("Thanks for giving me your time")
            exit()

        elif "who made you" in text or "who created you" in text:
            speak("I have been created by Alvise.")
                    
        elif 'joke' in text:
            speak(pyjokes.get_joke())

        elif 'search' in text or 'play' in text:
            query = text.replace("search", "")
            query = text.replace("play", "")        
            webbrowser.open(query)

        elif "who i am" in text:
            speak("If you talk then definitely your human.")

        elif "why you came to world" in text:
            speak("Thanks to Alvise. Further it's a secret")

        elif 'is love' in text:
            speak("It is 7th sense that destroy all other senses")

        elif "who are you" in text:
            speak("I am your virtual assistant created by Alvise")

        elif 'reason for you' in text:
            speak("I was created as a Minor project by Mister Alvise")
                
        elif 'shutdown system' in text:
                speak("Hold On a Sec ! Your system is on its way to shut down")
                subprocess.call('shutdown / p /f')

        elif "restart" in text:
            subprocess.call(["shutdown", "/r"])
        
        elif "where is" in text:                            # mi sa che non funziona
            text = text.replace("where is", "")
            location = text
            speak("User asked to Locate")
            speak(location)
            webbrowser.open("https://www.google.nl / maps / place/" + location + "")

        elif "weather" in text:
            # Google Open weather website
            # to get API of Open weather
            api_key = "Api key"
            base_url = "http://api.openweathermap.org / data / 2.5 / weather?"
            speak("What's the name of the city?")
            city_name = get_audio()
            complete_url = base_url + "appid =" + api_key + "&q =" + city_name
            response = requests.get(complete_url)
            x = response.json()
             
            if x["code"] != "404":
                y = x["main"]
                current_temperature = y["temp"]
                current_pressure = y["pressure"]
                current_humidiy = y["humidity"]
                z = x["weather"]
                weather_description = z[0]["description"]
                print(" Temperature (in kelvin unit) = " 
                + str(current_temperature)
                + "\n atmospheric pressure (in hPa unit) ="
                + str(current_pressure) 
                + "\n humidity (in percentage) = " 
                + str(current_humidiy) +"\n description = " 
                + str(weather_description)
                )
            else:
                speak(" City Not Found ")
```

I have tried setting up a new account for the google API and getting new credentials but it still gives me the same error of:

google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('invalid_grant: Bad Request', {'error': 'invalid_grant', 'error_description': 'Bad Request'})

Comment: delete 'token.json' and try again

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).